# Unable to create a look up field on Custom UI for Custom Metadata type

Tags: lookup, custom-metadata

Has anyone ever tried to create a look up (relationship to other custom metadata type)field on the Custom UI for Custom Metadata type?

The usual `<apex:inputfield>` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Custom Metadata Types are not writeable via `Apex`. Are you trying to manage them from a `Visualforce Page`?

Comment: Well you won't be able to use the standard bindings like `<apex:inputField>`. From the `Apex` perspective, those fields are not writeable.

Comment: Yes, Our requirement needed us to have custom buttons, which are not generally available so far on custom metadata types. So We implemented a complete custom UI for Custom Metadata management. Here is the link that shows the custom UI https://andyinthecloud.com/2015/06/28/custom-metadata-custom-uis-packaging-and-change-sets/.  While the custom UI for one of the 2 Custom Metadata types works fine. I am unable to implement the look up feature to another custom metadata type. <apex:inputField value="{!Capability_Persona.Capability__c}"/> doesnt work. Capability__c is a reference field.

Comment: Oh ok, do you suggest any workaround? Thanks in advance.